# Runtime Error 13 on Mac but not PC

Tags: macos, vba

Thank you for anyone that helps me with this.

I have written some VBA on a PC, but my copywriters use a mac and the Macros do not work. I get a run time error 13 on the following code:

```
If Range("Home_EPIC_Flag_Count").Value = 0 Then
```

is what gets highlighted yellow when I debug

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

 ' EPIC flag conditional testing macros

 If Range("Home_EPIC_Flag_Count").Value = 0 Then
      Me.Shapes("Home_EPIC_Flag").Visible = False
 Else
        Me.Shapes("Home_EPIC_Flag").Visible = True
 End If

 If Range("Rooms_EPIC_Flag_Count").Value = 0 Then
      Me.Shapes("Rooms_EPIC_Flag").Visible = False
 Else
        Me.Shapes("Rooms_EPIC_Flag").Visible = True
 End If

 If Range("Dining_EPIC_Flag_Count").Value = 0 Then
      Me.Shapes("Dining_EPIC_Flag").Visible = False
 Else
        Me.Shapes("Dining_EPIC_Flag").Visible = True
 End If

 If Range("Spa_EPIC_Flag_Count").Value = 0 Then
      Me.Shapes("Spa_EPIC_Flag").Visible = False
 Else
        Me.Shapes("Spa_EPIC_Flag").Visible = True
 End If

 If Range("Golf_EPIC_Flag_Count").Value = 0 Then
      Me.Shapes("Golf_EPIC_Flag").Visible = False
 Else
        Me.Shapes("Golf_EPIC_Flag").Visible = True
 End If

 If Range("LocalArea_EPIC_Flag_Count").Value = 0 Then
      Me.Shapes("LocalArea_EPIC_Flag").Visible = False
 Else
        Me.Shapes("LocalArea_EPIC_Flag").Visible = True
 End If

 If Range("Business_EPIC_Flag_Count").Value = 0 Then
      Me.Shapes("Business_EPIC_Flag").Visible = False
 Else
        Me.Shapes("Business_EPIC_Flag").Visible = True
 End If
```

Comment: Seems like at least in Excel 2011 there were some differences in how named ranges are scoped: eg http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macexcel/scope-of-named-ranges-in-excel-for-mac-2011/6a01cce0-c324-48c2-b356-d910c9e8acc2?db=5&auth=1

Answer (score 0):

A little refactoring will make your code more manageable (once you fix the named range issue)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

    Dim arr, x As Long
    arr = Array("Home", "Rooms", "Dining", "Spa", "Golf", "LocalArea", "Business")

    For x = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
         Me.Shapes(arr(x) & "_EPIC_Flag").Visible = _
                (Range(arr(x) & "_EPIC_Flag_Count").Value > 0)
    Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tim for your reply. Much appreciated, so why do you think refactoring will make it compatible with Mac? I noticed that once I sent the document as a zipped excel file, he could unzip it on his end and it worked fine. Any thoughts?

Comment: I didn't suggest that would fix the named range issue, hence the "once you fix the named range issue".